# How to pop elements from a tensor in Pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I want to drop/pop elements from a tensor in Pytorch, something similar to pop operation in python. In the following code , if the condition is met, it removes two elements from the array, current and the next.
I have a corresponding pytorch tensor. That means if the length of array is `10`, I have the tensor last_hidden_state of size `(1,10,768)`. After taking the mean of elements `last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:], last_hidden_state[:,index,:] and last_hidden_state[:,index+1,:]` I want to drop `last_hidden_state[:,index,:] and last_hidden_state[:,index+1,:]` Just like popping the current and next element from array. That means I should get a tensor of size `(1,8,768)` but with this code sometimes it returns `(1,7,768)` or `(1,6,768)`.
What is it that I am doing wrong? I am new to Pytorch tensors, thank you

```
def function_merge (prev_el, curr_el, next_el,index, array):
    if(curr_el.startswith('##') and next_el.startswith('##')):
         array[index-1] =  prev_el + curr_el + next_el
         array.pop(index) #remove current element
         array.pop(index) #remove next element

         last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:] = torch.add(last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:],last_hidden_state[:,index,:])
         last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:] = torch.add(last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:],last_hidden_state[:,index+1,:])
         last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:] = torch.mean(last_hidden_state[:,index-1,:])
            
         last_hidden_state = torch.cat((last_hidden_state[:,:index,:],last_hidden_state[:,index+2:,:]), axis=1)
         return array, last_hidden_state
```

Comment: nothing with your question but what actually you are doing I have curiosity because it reads up like something complicated....

Comment: maybe some this i = 2
T = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
T = torch.cat([T[0:i], T[i+1:]])

Comment: @ash I am trying to merge the bert tokens which are followed by ##tokens, so that I can average them to get the word embedding

Comment: Better to understand now